# Find the smallest positive integers m and n satisfying $(1 + i \sqrt{3})^{m} = (1 + i)^{n}$.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, systems-of-equations

I've tried altering both sides to polar form and using DeMoivre's formula to see if there's a way to solve this, but I can't quite figure it out. So far my work is:

$(1 + i \sqrt{3})^{m} = (1 + i)^{n} \Rightarrow$
$2m(cos(\frac{m\pi}{3}) + i sin(\frac{m\pi}{3})) = \sqrt{2}n (cos(\frac{n\pi}{2}) + isin(\frac{n\pi}{2}))$

This makes it even longer, but I tried making this into a system of equations like so:

$2m = \sqrt{2}n; \frac{m\pi}{3} = \frac{n\pi}{2}$

This just ends up being something like $3 = \sqrt{2}$, so it's definitely not the right way to go about this problem. I'm not sure how else to work it out? Maybe I'm ignorant to an important trig identity or something?

Comment: How are you obtaining $2m$ and $\sqrt{2}n$? Is it by any chance, $2^m$ and $\left( \sqrt{2} \right)^n$?

Comment: Note that $\cos(x) = \cos(y)$ and $\sin(x) = \sin(y)$ do not necessarily imply that $x = y$.

Comment: From $(\sqrt{2})^n = 2^m = (\sqrt{2})^{2m}$, we have $n = 2m$.  Substitute that into the original equation for $n$:
$$(1 + i\sqrt{3})^m = (1+i)^{2m} = (2i)^m$$
Divide both sides by $(2i)^m$:
$$\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} - \frac{1}{2}i\right)^m = 1$$
You might be able to finish from here.

Comment: $(m,n)=(12,24)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have

$$2^me^{m\pi i/3}=2^{n/2}e^{n\pi i/4}$$

$$\iff2^{\dfrac{2m- n}2}=e^{\dfrac{\pi i(3n-4m)}{12}}$$

Taking modulus is both sides we need  $$\dfrac{2m- n}2=0\implies n=2m$$

and consequently, $$e^{\dfrac{\pi i(3n-4m)}{12}}=1=e^{2r\pi i}$$ where $r$ is any integer $$\implies 2r\pi i=\dfrac{\pi i(3n-4m)}{12}$$

Use $n=2m$

Comment: Why is only $2e^{i\pi/3}=1+i\sqrt{3}$? Why not take $2e^{7i\pi/3}$? As far as I know, $e^{i\theta}$ is periodic at an interval of $2\pi$.

Comment: @Dave, We can actually choose $$(2e^{2a\pi i+i\pi/3})^m=(2^{1/2}e^{2b\pi i+i\pi/4})^n$$